# WindowsForms - C# - ReportViewer - "Resolução Full HD" Remover Bordas

Tags: c#, winforms, reportviewer

Estou utilizando o Report Viewer, os dados aparecem normal, porem aparece uma borda em branco em computadores com resolução alta como FULL HD por exemplo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código do carregamento do formulário.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Propriedades do report.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Instalei o EXE em outra maquina de resolução menor e o relatório foi gerado sem a borda. Gostaria de que retirar essa borda ou saber se tem alguma configuração para o report expandir com a resolução.

Comment: Por favor, coloque o código por escrito na pergunta para que possamos analisar ele.

Answer (score 0):

Saudações.

No meu projeto eu resolvi com o código a seguir:

Primeiro crie o método ***ConfigurarMargens***.

```
private void ConfigurarMargens()
{
   // Configura as margens do relatório
   System.Drawing.Printing.PageSettings pg = new System.Drawing.Printing.PageSettings();
   pg.Margins.Top = 0;
   pg.Margins.Bottom = 0;
   pg.Margins.Left = 0;
   pg.Margins.Right = 0;
   pg.Landscape = false;
   this.reportViewer1.SetPageSettings(pg);
   this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
}
```

No Evento **Load** do Form faça assim:

```
private void frmMeuForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
   ConfigurarMargens(); 
}
```

Certifique-se de estar utilizando a biblioteca:

```
using System.Drawing;
```

Espero que este código lhe sirva como me serviu.